# Sass @extend sibling selector referencing parent selector (ampersand)

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to accomplish the following CSS output with Sass:

```
.selector1 + .selector1, .selector2 + .selector2 {
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

The @extend functionality should do the job:

```
%sibling-selector {
    & + & {
        margin-top: -80px;  
    }
}
.selector1 {
    @extend %sibling-selector;
}
.selector2 {
    @extend %sibling-selector;
}
```

But it seems the extend function has problems with the two parent references (&) in the extend only class definition (%sibling-selector).
This is the output:

```
.selector1 + .selector1, .selector2 + .selector1, 
.selector1 + .selector2, .selector2 + .selector2 {
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

So the @extend function is making sibling selectors for each combination of selectors that use the @extend definition.

While I would expect the @extend stays in the "scope" of the current selector, and so the ampersand is replaced by the current selector.
Is this a bug or a feature? :-)

I know I could use a mixin for this job,

```
@mixin sibling-selector {
    & + & {
        margin-top: -80px;
    }
}
.selector1 {
    @include sibling-selector;
}
.selector2 {
    @include sibling-selector;
}
```

but that would create duplicate CSS definitions:

```
.selector1 + .selector1 {
    margin-top: -80px;
}
.selector2 + .selector2 {
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

Is there a way to get it right with Sass?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me -- like an edge case that isn't really accounted for. You might want to file an issue with the project on GitHub. In the meantime: (1) the `@mixin` approach or else (2) just code the desired output as vanilla CSS and call it a day.

Comment: You should probably file a bug report. https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues

Comment: Added a new issue on github: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/848

Answer (score 1):

It seems `@extend` is not the way to get the wanted result: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/848#issuecomment-20903684

So to "automate" the creation of the sibling selectors I've used a small `@each` loop to create a list of selectors.

```
$siblingSelectors: ();
@each $selector in selector1 selector2 selector3 {
    $classSelector: unquote('.prefix-' + $selector);
    $siblingSelectors: append($siblingSelectors, unquote($classSelector + ' + ' + $classSelector), comma);
}

#{$siblingSelectors} {
    margin-top: 80px;
    &.large {
        margin-top: -100px;
    }
}
```

Which gives the following result:

```
.prefix-selector1 + .prefix-selector1, .prefix-selector2 + .prefix-selector2 {
    margin-top: -80px;
}
.prefix-selector1 + .prefix-selector1.large, .prefix-selector2 + .prefix-selector2.large {
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```